# Excel formula like MLM

Tags: excel, formula, mlm

As the picture, the explanation as below:

[image]

[image]

J.Li and E.Bn will join into R.B team, then you can see the Level 1 those have 1. Then J.Li and E.Bn they also have their team, so that B.Ko and K.Un will join into J.Li team, you can also see that Level 1 those have 1 too, and C.Ki and X.Pq will join into E.Bn team, in his Level 1 also has 1 too, in this moment, you can see team R.B, the Level 2 will be appear 2 and 2, because his 2 members J.Li and E.Bn they also have members, that’s why will put the number into his Level 2, the case in Level 3 is same.

I want to know that how to do this formula is there are many member and new team create under this sheet? I have try to find spreadsheet formula, but no idea for this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 1st column is column A.

Level 1 : values is always 1

Level 2 : is the count of how many times 'MEMBER's name appear in column A.

solution >  a `countif()` formula should do. with the above as the condition.

Level 3 : is the sum of 'MEMBER's level 2.

solution >  do `sumif()` on column F (level 2). same as level 2 condition.

Hope it solves.. (: